# ES6 version of Underscore's _.indexBy()

Tags: ecmascript-6, underscore.js

Underscore has a neat function `indexBy` for mapping an array on a certain key. From the documentation:

> _.indexBy(list, iteratee, context)
>
> Given a list, and an iteratee function that returns a key for each element in the list (or a property name), returns an object with an index of each item. Just like groupBy, but for when you know your keys are unique.

Example of use:

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.indexBy(stooges, 'age');
  => {
    "40": {name: 'moe', age: 40},
    "50": {name: 'larry', age: 50},
    "60": {name: 'curly', age: 60}
  }
```

How can this be written i pure ES6 without libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function implements the full definition of `_.indexBy` with `iteratee` and `context`:

```
function indexBy(list, iteratee, context) {
    return list.reduce((map, obj) => {
        const key = typeof iteratee === 'string' ? obj[iteratee] : iteratee.call(context, obj);
        map[key] = obj;
        return map;
    }, {});
}
```